# How to implement number of chances in a game without using nested if else

Tags: java

I am developing an school assignment java multiple choice game where you have to give the user a number of chances to answer correctly,

My question is without using a set of nested if else if in the game, what is the simplest way that it can be done for the game to work properly and the way it should be working

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is write a while loop like following:

```
int tries = 0;
boolean isCorrect = false;
while(tries++ < 10 || !isCorrect) {
    System.out.println("Chance #" + tries);

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    isCorrect = evaluateAnswer(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

This way the amount of tries start at 1 rather than 0. However if you want to add multiple questions you will need to put this in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Well have you heard switch?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Alternately if the Number of answers is Fixed you can use Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WHILE loop :

```
int attemps = 0;
boolean correct = false;
do{
    correct = evalTheAnswers();// évaluate the answers
    attemps++; 
}while(!correct || attemps < attempsLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

A switch-case-statement would be the most suitable approach.

I took the following example from the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

```
    int month = 8;
    String monthString;
    switch (month) {
        case 1:  monthString = "January";
                 break;
        case 2:  monthString = "February";
                 break;
        case 3:  monthString = "March";
                 break;
        case 4:  monthString = "April";
                 break;
        case 5:  monthString = "May";
                 break;
        case 6:  monthString = "June";
                 break;
        case 7:  monthString = "July";
                 break;
        case 8:  monthString = "August";
                 break;
        case 9:  monthString = "September";
                 break;
        case 10: monthString = "October";
                 break;
        case 11: monthString = "November";
                 break;
        case 12: monthString = "December";
                 break;
        default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                 break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
```

**Note:** There was a time when the switch statement could not handle Strings. But that changed in JDK1.7.

**Edit:**
Of course, that switch-case statement would have to be surrounded by a loop. For this, you have several options.

1. for-loop (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++):
   In that case, the "i <= 3" would be the amount of changes the user/player has.
2. while-loop:
   In the "default:" of the switch-case-statement you would increment the the int chances by 1 and would go through the switch-case-statement as long as the max amount of chances had not been reached.

   `int chances = 0;
   while (chances < 3) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest combining the answers by  MicroProgram and ikken, i.e. a while loop checking *both* the number of attempts and if the answer is correct. The `do-while` could be a good idea depending on how your program works.

Comment: I mean depending on how the rest of your code looks. It's up to you to decide whether to use `while` or `do-while`.